# Uploading a large number of fonts and showing sample in drop-down list/input field search font highlight

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am creating a text editor in the style of Microsoft Office 2010. Alike Microsoft Office, I would like to have a drop down list of all fonts in the following format:

```
<li>Arial</li>
<li>Arial Black</li>
<li>Arial Narrow</li>
```

However, there are over 500 fonts submitted to Google Fonts and even uploading a fraction of them, implementing them into my list with a preview of the font will take hours upon hours of repetitive behavior.

Is there a way, using the likes of Javascript/JQuery/PHP to speed up the process, search a directory on my site and each folder is turned into a new list item or whatnot?

Google Fonts Directory: https://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/

Hopefully this is useful to mention at the moment; Next to the drop down button to show this list, there is an input field of which you can enter a font. I would like to show some form of highlighing if the user manually starts typing.

Best Regards,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

There is an [API](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/developer_api) of Google Web Fonts. The API gives access to the data in JSON, so you can use JavaScript.

Comment: This requires a Google API key, of which I do not have and cannot obtain at this moment of time. If this is the best way, I shall wait until I have a Google API Key, but for the time being, is there another way?

Comment: I've found this: http://phat-reaction.com/googlefonts.php And I think this is want you want: http://phat-reaction.com/googlefonts.php?format=json